# Bigquery Multiple Tables access with Terraform with dynamic table name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create multiple table access using a local list and pass values into a single resource block:

```
locals {
   map_of_all_tables = [
     {
     "table_name" : "table1"
     "dataset_id" : "dataset_id1"
     "table_id"   : "table_id1"
     },
     {
     "table_name" : "table2"
     "dataset_id" : "dataset_id2"
     "table_id"   : "table_id2"
     }
   ]
 }
resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access" {
   count = contains(var.table_name_list, local.map_of_all_tables[*].table_name) ? <(no. of matching tables)> : 0
   project = "test-project1"
   dataset_id = locals.map_of_all_tables[<indexOfMatchingTable>].dataset_id #dataset_id of matching table name
   table_id = locals.map_of_all_tables[<indexOfMatchingTable>].table_id #table_id of matching table name
   role = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
   member = "user:${var.user_email}"
 }
```

If the var.table_name_list contains any number of tables which matches the table name in the local list, it should create the resource "access[]" for each of these tables using the dataset ids and table ids from the list for these particular tables. Is this possible in Terraform? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a list of `tables` in `var.table_name_list` var for which access needs to be given. All the tables are present in `local.map_of_all_tables` local variable & you want to filter it against `var.table_name_list`.

I'm assuming above scenarios as you haven't told how `var.table_name_list` looks like..

```
locals {
  map_of_all_tables = [
    {
      "table_name" : "table1"
      "dataset_id" : "dataset_id1"
      "table_id" : "table_id1"
    },
    {
      "table_name" : "table2"
      "dataset_id" : "dataset_id2"
      "table_id" : "table_id2"
    },
    {
      "table_name" : "table3"
      "dataset_id" : "dataset_id3"
      "table_id" : "table_id3"
    }
  ]

  ## this will filter
  table_access_list = [for table in local.map_of_all_tables : table if contains(var.table_name_list, table.table_name)]

}

## assuming the var like below
variable "table_name_list" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["table1", "table2"]
}

## output displaying the filtered tables
output "table_access_list" {
    value = local.table_access_list
}
```

Then, you could iterate over the `local.table_access_list` var to grant access only to desired tables.

```
resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access" {
   for_each = {
      for table_access in local.table_access_list : table_access.table_name => table_access
   }
   project = "test-project1-${each.value.table_name}"
   dataset_id = local.table_access_list[each.value.table_name].dataset_id #dataset_id of matching table name
   table_id = local.table_access_list[each.value.table_name].table_id #table_id of matching table name
   role = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
   member = "user:${var.user_email}"
}
```

Comment: yes you have understood the question correctly. I can follow your steps what youre trying to do until the dataset_id inside the resource. 
The `local.table_access_list` is now the list of matching tables. For example if the table2 and table3 are matching, this list is now :

`{
      "table_name" : "table2"
      "dataset_id" : "dataset_id2"
      "table_id" : "table_id2"
    },
    {
      "table_name" : "table3"
      "dataset_id" : "dataset_id3"
      "table_id" : "table_id3"
    }`

Then in the resource , for dataset_id why not use the dataset_id based on the index?

Comment: so for example :
`resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access" {
   count = length(table_access_list)
   project = "test-project1"
   dataset_id = local.table_access_list[count.index].dataset_id #dataset_id of matching table name
   table_id = local.table_access_list[count.index].table_id #table_id of matching table name
   role = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
   member = "user:${var.user_email}"
}
`

Comment: Have you tried my answer? From your input, I see its a `flattened` output. It doesn’t matter what fields I use to iterate as long as they are unique. 
Also, I used `for_each` instead of `count`, so `[count.index]` is irrelevant. If you use `count`, then yours should work. But, AFAIK, your question is about filtering rather this right?

Comment: I tried your approach and it gave me an invalid index error saying local access list is a tuple with 2 elements

However with the resource as I showed in my 2nd comment works exactly as I expect it to so I am accepting your answer since the main part that i was missing was explained very nicely by you so thank you :)